# Insufficient mapping in Entity Framework with fluent api (Database First) on 1:1 relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql, ef-database-first

I have these classes and need to map then with relationship 1:1, but I not have yet a good knowledge for fluent API and I have received this error at runtime (debug):

> "erro 3015: Problema nos fragmentos do mapeamento a partir das linhas 6, 22, 
>   191:Restrição de chave estrangeira 'OperadorModel_OpCadastros1' da tabela OperadorModel 
>   (OpCadastros1_OperadorId) para a tabela OperadorModel (id):: Mapeamento insuficiente: a 
>   chave estrangeira deve ser mapeada para algum AssociationSet ou EntitySets participantes 
>   de uma associação de chave estrangeira no lado conceitual."

Something like:

> "Error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments from lines 6, 22, 191: a foreign key constraint 
>   'OperadorModel_OpCadastros1' table OperadorModel (OpCadastros1_OperadorId) for the table 
>   OperadorModel (id) :: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped for some 
>   AssociationSet EntitySets or participating in a foreign key association in the conceptual. "

How to solve this problem?

The code is below. Thankfully, and sorry for my bad English.

```
public class OperadorModel
{
    public int OperadorId { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public bool TiraMenu { get; set; }

    public virtual OpCadastros1Model OpCadastros1 { get; set; }
}

public class OpCadastros1Model
{
    public int OperadorId { get; set; }

    public virtual OperadorModel Operador { get; set; }

    #region Apoio

    [Column("cad_apoio_ac")]
    [Display(Description = "Acessar", GroupName = "Cadastros", Name = "Laboratórios de Apoio")]
    public bool AcApoio { get; set; }

    [Column("cad_apoio_ad")]
    [Display(Description = "Adicionar", GroupName = "Cadastros", Name = "Laboratórios de Apoio")]
    public bool AdApoio { get; set; }

    [Column("cad_apoio_md")]
    [Display(Description = "Modificar", GroupName = "Cadastros", Name = "Laboratórios de Apoio")]
    public bool MdApoio { get; set; }

    [Column("cad_apoio_co")]
    [Display(Description = "Consultar", GroupName = "Cadastros", Name = "Laboratórios de Apoio")]
    public bool CoApoio { get; set; }

    [Column("cad_apoio_ex")]
    [Display(Description = "Excluir", GroupName = "Cadastros", Name = "Laboratórios de Apoio")]
    public bool ExApoio { get;  set; }

    #endregion
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<OperadorModel>()
        .HasKey(op => op.OperadorId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OpCadastros1Model>()
        .HasKey(cad => cad.OperadorId)
        .HasRequired(cad => cad.Operador)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(cad => cad.OpCadastros1);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OperadorModel>().ToTable("operador", "public");
    modelBuilder.Entity<OpCadastros1Model>().ToTable("operador", "public");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue here is a need to specify the key to use explicitly as convention for how they are to be named is quite strict (it expects a column named ID - *I think*), and something **like** this should fix the problem:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OperadorModel>()
    .HasKey(op => op.OperadorId)
    .HasOptional(op => op.OpCadastros1)
    .Map(f => f.MapKey("OperadorID"));
```

After I wrote that I and looked for what was likely your ID, I realized the ID column is the same name in the Model for both objects...

Comment: Yes @Mattew, the "ID" is the same for both classes, and these referenced for some table.

Comment: Does specifying the column name explicitly like above fix your issue?

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Note in the fluent code above that is column name in the database and not the model property name if they are not the same.

Comment: In database the column name is "id"; the reference for it on model is "OperadorId".

Comment: So based on that the text in `""` would be `ID` and not `OperadorID`